# SQL - How to alter table while doing INSERT INTO?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table, insert-into

I have 2 similar tables Table1 and Table2. I want to bring over some records from Table1 to Table2, for which I used the INSERT INTO statement. There is a column "EntityColumn" in Table1 with unique values like C1, C2, C3 etc.

For every record that is copied from Table1 to Table2, I want a column added to a third table - Table3 - and the name of the column should be the value of the EntityColumn field. Attached image should provide depict this.

[image]

Please tell me how this can be achieved.

Comment: Do you really need to add it on the fly to a physical table? YOu could just create a crosstab view over the top of it. What you're really after is a crosstab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot readily do this.

The logically approach would be to write a trigger, and for each value being inserted, you would alter the third table and add a column.

However, a DML trigger cannot run an alter table statement to add a column, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Instead of adding columns to Table3 as and when the rows are copied to Table2, is there a way to add the columns once all the rows have been copied to Table2?

Comment: @GuhanMurugesan . . . It sounds like you need a stored procedure that will run dynamic SQL to do what you want.  So, yes, it is possible.